# how to hover group of elements on hovering another element?

Tags: css, styles, mousehover, onhover

I have one div `.product-wrapper` that contains group of elements. And I need to animate them all on hovering on the div container.

the problem is I only get animation when hovering on the main container div `.product-wrapper`, and whenever I hover any other element included inside the container `.product-wrapper` all animation get lose.

```css
    .product-wrapper{
      width: 270px;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #9999;
    }

    .product-wrapper>img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 180px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      transition: transform .5s; /* Animation */
    }
    .product-wrapper>img:hover{
      transform: scale(1.5); 
    }

    .product-wrapper .title{
      background-color: #9999;
      border-top: 1px solid #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 20px;
      transition: .3s ease;
    }
    .product-wrapper:hover .title{ 
      opacity: 1;
      top: 10%;
      box-shadow:0 0 0 200vmax rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

    .product-wrapper>a {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #9999;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        transition: .5s ease;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .product-wrapper:hover a{ 
        opacity: 1;
        bottom: 5%;
    }

    .product-wrapper>div {
        background-color: #9999;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .product-wrapper:hover div{ 
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 30%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="product-wrapper">
  <span class="title">product name</span>
  <img class="zoomImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-drawn-illustration-container-ship-sea_23-2149149324.jpg?w=2000" />
  <a asp-controller="News" asp-action="PalNew" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="ajax">more ...</a>
  <div class="ribbon">product name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the difference (if there is one) between product-wrapper and 'the container'. Is there an overall container with all products in it which when hovered causes all products to show their further information? Perhaps you could edit your snippet to show more than one product and the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code was that you weren't telling your code to change when hovered on parent element but rather specifically on the img element itself. Here's what I could do with your question

css:

```css
.product-wrapper{
    width: 270px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #9999;
  }

  .product-wrapper>img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: transform .5s; /* Animation */
  }
  .product-wrapper:hover > img{
    transform: scale(1.5); 
  }

  .product-wrapper .title{
    background-color: #9999;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .3s ease;
  }
  .product-wrapper:hover .title{ 
    opacity: 1;
    top: 10%;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 200vmax rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }

  .product-wrapper>a {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #9999;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
      transition: .5s ease;
      z-index: 2;
  }
  .product-wrapper:hover a{ 
      opacity: 1;
      bottom: 5%;
  }

  .product-wrapper>div {
      background-color: #9999;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  .product-wrapper:hover div{ 
      opacity: 0;
      bottom: 30%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="product-wrapper">
  <span class="title">product name</span>
  <img class="zoomImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-drawn-illustration-container-ship-sea_23-2149149324.jpg?w=2000" />
  <a asp-controller="News" asp-action="PalNew" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="ajax">more ...</a>
  <div class="ribbon">product name</div>
</div>
```

not much changed just told the code to transform the child when the parent is hovered. hope this helped.